# How is sudo dangerous?

Tags: debian, security, sudo

Debian has an entry on Docker, which warns :

[Docker group membership is more dangerous than sudo](https://wiki.debian.org/Docker)

That reads to me as an insinuation that sudo is itself dangerous (albeit less than Docker (group membership)).

How is sudo dangerous (perhaps generally, and beyond misconfiguration)?
*In particular though*, how does *Debian* mean here that sudo is dangerous?

Comment: `sudo` is often set up so that a user can run anything they like as root, so e.g. wiping the disk or removing all files is just one command, or one typo, away. But at least it asks for the password every once in a while.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, so not quite misconfiguration, just overly permissive config. I'll wait for answers to roll in, but is that *the* sense in which Debian means to imply sudo is dangerous, or just one potential pitfall that you know of ?

Comment: another thing might be that people probably have the idea that even if they add an account to a friend, they probably shouldn't give them unrestricted `sudo` permissions, because that's dangerous: the user could do all sorts of nasty stuff. But that Docker might allow for all the same stuff because it's setuid might not be as commonly known. So a warning might be in order because of that. (Yes, I know, `sudo` could be set up to allow just a limited set of commands, but a common use-case seems to be just allowing people in some group to do anything.) I don't _know_ what Debian means though.

Comment: Why don't you just read the full warning box of your link? It is literally explained there what problem the authors see with docker vs sudo.

Comment: @FelixJN I've read it. Have you ? It describes risks of *Docker group membership* in contrast/comparison with sudo. It does not describe dangers of sudo itself (nor would I expect it to, that's not the article's apropos).

Comment: I see, I think this is merely a misunderstanding in the formulation: Read this in combination with the last sentence where it is suggested that docker commands may only be run with sudo. "docker membership is more dangerous than sudo" thus means if you want to allow someone to run docker commands, add them to sudo instead of docker. Because docker allows arbitrary code injection without password failsave. If someone is in sudo, it might still be possible that an attacker gets root access, but it is not as simple as the docker route to root.

Comment: I don't see how this is a question for [unix.se]. It seems to be more appropriate for [english.se] or [ell.se]. The querent seems confused about the meaning of an English sentence, they simply don't understand that a comparative like "A is more X than B" does not in any way imply that B is X. E.g. "a tiger is more deadly than a hamster" does not imply that hamsters are deadly, nor does it in fact imply that tigers are deadly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm aware of alternate ways it might be read and interpreted, but thanks for your eagerness to smugly flaunt your unique enlightenment. "Tigers are more deadly than lions." See? This comparative formulation can cut both ways, which I'm sure you knew (yet opted to lean towards a view which serves to shut others down). sudo *may indeed* be considered dangerous by some, evidenced by the quality answers below. Even if my reading of the source were unambiguously, unequivocally wrong, there is merit to discussing general pitfalls of sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both docker and sudo can give full root access. The worst case risk of both is basically the same.

If a hacker gets full root access then recovery usually involves rebuilding your server. They can do anything and hide anything on your server.

So sudo is a lesser risk because root access can be limited by configuration.  Sudo has configurable control over which commands it will execute for a user.  There is also (usually) the requirement for a sudo user to enter a password which may stop some malicious attacks if a hacker gains access to that user's account; the hacker may have access but not the password.

With docker there is no such ability to configure making it "more dangerous". If you know the right "docker run" command you can get a commandline on the docker host as root. Example:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host alpine:latest nsenter -t 1 /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix permissions are set up so that a normally privileged user can do minimal permanent damage to the system.

The sudo command elevates a trusted user's permission to root, which can do anything to the system, including make changes to the operating system that will cause it to malfunction.  This makes sudo, and root access in general, dangerous.

Naive users who have sudo access frequently just prefix every command with sudo, even ones that don't need root access, and ones that should run as with the user's permissions instead of root.  Users are also frequently not careful, and a command with a typo run as root can have extremely bad consequences.  Even when the command in question is correct and isn't intended to damage the operating system, it can cause damage to the user's account just because it is run as root, making sudo especially dangerous.  Add to that the inexperience of the user and the likelihood they'll run any command they find in google with sudo without looking up what it does, this can make sudo catastrophically dangerous.

The default permissions given by allowing sudo access are full root access.  However, sudo can be fine tuned to give much more limited access, either to elevate to specific non-root users or groups, or to limit root (or non-root) access to specific commands.  However, this requires special configuration, and is not typically what is meant when "sudo" access is requested.

Comment: It isn't inherently in sudo that it only elevates a user's permissions to that of root.

Comment: personally i run pgcli using 'sudo -u postgres pgcli' to run pgcli/psql against the cluster as the postgres administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Many admins doesn't want to in sudoers enumerate what different groups of users should be able to do so...

they add every admin to the sudo group and enables
the default '%sudo ALL=ALL...' item in sudoers.

**A better usage of sudo**

Think about roles instead, so
if you have a group of admins which is responsible for the postgres cluster in a part of the system:

add those users to a group in the system which is able to run the postgres admin commands as the postgres super user (postgres in debian.)
Ergo: they can only modify postgres itself, for example create new databases/roles in postgres/users in postgres but NOT modify how postgres maps system users to postgres users for example.

**Docker and sudo**

The docker daemon is marked as suid root, so think roles for docker. For each application of docker, turn that into a role, and force the users to start docker using sudo.

Sudo is configured such that each role has its own definition inside sudoers.d

I don't use docker, so could someone give samples of how they use docker ?
Begin with removing the exec bit for other users on the docker commands ie:

```
chmod o-x /usr/bin/docker
```

In that ways do you invoke docker ?
Do you have multiple docker images ? If so, a role for each and a definition for each in sudoers.d.